# Is every abstract simplicial complex the independence complex of a simple graph?

Tags: graph-theory, simplicial-complex, algebraic-combinatorics

Given a simple (no loops, no multi-edges) undirected graph $G$ on $n$-vertices, one can assign an abstract simplicial complex known as the independence complex (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_complex) on $n$-vertices whose faces are exactly the independent sets of the graph $G$.

My question is: Is every abstract simplicial complex the independence complex of a simple graph?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $X$ is a subset of the vertex set of a graph and if every $2$-element subset of $X$ is independent, then $X$ itself is independent. So the simplicial complex consisting of all the $\leq2$-element subsets of $\{1,2,3\}$ is not the independence complex of any graph.

Answer (score 2):

As @AndreasBlass said, this is not true because whenever all the 2-faces of a simplex are present in the complex, the the simplex itself is present. This is a characterization of the clique complexes. And actually, the independence complex of a graph $G$ is the clique complex of the complement of $G$, so this makes sense.

Comment: I see, thanks. Do you know a proof (or a reference) of this fact that if a simplicial complex does not have all $2$-element subsets as faces, then it must the the independence complex of a graph?

Comment: No, what I meant was fundamentally the same as Andreas : for an independance complex $C$, if there is a set ${X_n}$ such that $\forall i,j, {X_i,X_j} \in C$, then the simplex ${X_n}_n$ is itself in $C$.

Comment: This property is a characterization of [clique complexes][1] (because clique complexes are the clique complexes built from their own 2-skeleton). And the clique complex of a graph $G$ is equivalent to the independence complex of the complement graph of $G$.

 [1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_complex